# Prevent Network Manager from starting wpa_supplicant

Tags: networkmanager, wpa-supplicant, dhcpcd

I am using a Debian distribution (based on stretch) and I am trying to prevent `NetworkManager` (NM) from starting the `wpa_supplicant` service.

The reason I want to do that is that I want `dhcpcd` to handle my wireless interfaces and connections. I have already configured the NM to prevent controlling the wifi interfaces, but I don't what the `wpa_supplicant` service does as dhcpcd also spawns a process of `wpa_supplicant`.

What are the options besides ditching `dhcpcd` and moving all the power to NM?

**References**

1. [Prevent NM from controlling an interface](https://support.qacafe.com/knowledge-base/how-do-i-prevent-network-manager-from-controlling-an-interface/)
2. [NetworkManager configuration](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/NetworkManager.conf.html)

Comment: see `nohook wpa_supplicant` for dhcpcd .... I usually ditch NetworkManager/resolvconf

Comment: Thx. But I am looking smth similar for Network Manager